Device Mapper Snapshot Stored In An Expanding File
Is there a way to create a block device that is backed by a file that grows in size as the block device is written to?
I'm looking to use device mapper snapshots (ie: dmsetup create command that specifies snapshot as the type of item to create) and according to the documentation the snapshot needs to be stored on a block device.  One way to create this block device is by using losetup to turn a file into a block device.  However, that requires as fixed size file.  I'm trying to figure out if there is any way to not need a fixed size file but instead have the file that backs the block device that backs the snapshot grow as the snapshot grows.
